# How can I write pure HTML like <img> tag in ERB?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

I want to replace `<%= link_to image_tag ("picture.png")` with something like this: `<img src="/path/picture.png" />` in a file.html.erb

But when I do this, and it works without any error, but no picture shows up on the page.

Comment: Which Rails version you are using ? and  Are you using Asset pipeline concept?

Comment: `rails -v` outputs this `Rails 4.2.4`

Comment: at the same time, where are you putting the `picture.png` file in your app?

Comment: I have kept `picture.png` in `app/assets/images` directory.

Comment: What is the path to the image that you are expecting? 
With Rails 4.2.4 you should be using the asset pipeline, and your image should be in app/assets/images then your image_tag should work with just the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is my answer for you:

By default, rails will be serving all your assets from inside the `public` folder.

You are able to put images in the `assets/images` folder and render those because of the `assets pipeline`.

However, if you want to use the native

```
<img src="/path/picture.png" />
```

like you asked in your question, then you should understand that the path you are specifying in your `src`(src="/path/picture.png") will be taken relative to the `public` folder of your application.

To make the above work then, `picture.png` will not be placed in `app/assets/images/picture.png`, but should be placed in `public/path/picture.png`.

By convention though, you will want to place the picture in:

```
public/images/picture.png
```

So, you should then use the `img` tag in your view as follow:

```
<img src="/images/picture.png" />
```

This will work fine for the purpose of your question.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
<img src="<%= image_path('picture.png') %>" />
```

But I don't see why this is better than:

```
<%= image_tag("picture.png") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 4.2, You must use asset pipeline,

So You should use `image_tag` or `image_path` instead `src` in `Html` tag.

Ex.

```
image_path("rails.png") # => "/assets/rails.png"

<img src="<%= image_path('rails.png') %>" />
```

or

```
   image_tag("rails.png")
   # => <img alt="Rails" src="/assets/rails.png" />
```

Please Read about [asset_pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: `asset_pipeline` link is great, solution suggested by you didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To render an image `picture.png` placed in `app/assets/images` directory, you could also directly specify the `assets` directory in the image path as:

```
<img src="/assets/picture.png" />
```