# Add image within an <a></a> in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add an image tag within an a tag in rails. Here is the original code:

```
<a href="assets/img/main/img9.jpg" title="Project One" data-rel="gallery" class="thumbnail fancybox">
    <img alt="" src="assets/img/main/img9.jpg" class="full-width img-responsive">
    <span class="portfolio-box-in rounded-x">
       <i class="r icon-magnifier-add"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Here is my rails translation but when I try to translate it into rails it does not get the same look as it supposed to in the original code.

```
<%= link_to "creative/main/img18.jpg", :class => "thumbnail fancybox", data_rel:"gallery", title: "Project Three"  do %>

    <%= image_tag "creative/main/img18.jpg", :class => "full-width img-
    responsive" %>
    <span class="rounded-x portfolio-box-in">
    <i class="icon-magnifier-add"></i>
    </span>

<%end%>
```

Here is how its supposed to look [image: first look]

And when you click on the magnifying glass it looks like this:

[image: Second]

On my translation it does not show the magnifying glass and when I click on it it looks like the second picture.

[image: Third]

[image: Fourth]

Any help to get the right format would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried what was suggested to me:

```
        <%= link_to image_path("creative/main/img18.jpg"), class: "thumbnail fancybox", data: { rel: "gallery" }, title: "Project Three"  do %>
        <%= image_tag "creative/main/img18.jpg", class: "full-width img-responsive" %>
        <span class="rounded-x portfolio-box-in">
                <i class="icon-magnifier-add"></i>
        </span>
            <% end %>
```

When I tried that I didn't get the full magnifying glass and when I click on the image it does not load the larger image:

[image: Fifth image]
[image: sixth image]

**UPDATE 2**

I examined the html generated and it doesn't appear to be off from the original:

Generated from suggestion:

```
<a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-rel="gallery" title="Project Three" href="/image.creative%2Fmain%2Fimg18.jpg">
    <img class="full-width img-responsive" src="/assets/creative/main/img18-972c688b1a840ae0a8ec9b22012ae6c4aa69ca6894da2029277fa2c163b41fc0.jpg" alt="Img18" />
    <span class="rounded-x portfolio-box-in">
       <i class="icon-magnifier-add"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Here is the original html from the working code:

```
<a href="assets/img/main/img18.jpg" title="Project Three" data-rel="gallery" class="thumbnail fancybox">
        <img alt="" src="assets/img/main/img18.jpg" class="full-width img-responsive">
        <span class="portfolio-box-in rounded-x">
           <i class="r icon-magnifier-add"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
```

Comment: If you downvoted can you please let me know why

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how about formatting that code so it's not indented over 20+ spaces? Help us help you.

Comment: @ChrisPeters I made the changes thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You should select "view source" in your browser to see the actual HTML the `erb` generated. Comparing the new HTML to the old HTML is more valuable for discovering any unintended differences.

Comment: @eiko thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dp7 I was able to figure out my issue. There were two issues that I found out I had. The first was the font awesome icon this line `icon-magnifier-add` This line appeared to be from another library not font awesome so I fixed it to appear as `fa fa-search-plus` the second issue was that the second image that enlarges was not loading because the app could not find the image. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757348/7039895 when I translate an

```
<%= link_to ("assets/creative/main/img18.jpg"), :class => "thumbnail fancybox", data: { rel: "gallery" }, title: "Project Three"  do %>
    <%= image_tag "creative/main/img18.jpg", :class => "full-width img-responsive" %>
    <span class="rounded-x portfolio-box-in">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tested code, you can try once:

```
<%= link_to image_path("creative/main/img18.jpg"), class: "thumbnail fancybox", data: { rel: "gallery" }, title: "Project Three"  do %>
 <%= image_tag "creative/main/img18.jpg", class: "full-width img-responsive" %>
 <span class="rounded-x portfolio-box-in">
   <i class="icon-magnifier-add"></i>
 </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @JermaineSubia please inspect the generated HTML code from the browser and compare if you find any dissimilarity.

Comment: Check the update I examined the html and thank you for suggesting that I completely did not even think of doing that they look similar...